# Typescript notation: Observable<Array<Example>> different to Observable<Example[]>

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Is

```
Observable<Array<Example>>
```

any different to

```
Observable<Example[]>
```

when used in typescript? I'm using RxJS to emit an observable which emits an array of Example objects.

Comment: deleted my answer you can check here :  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok thanks, can you delete this question please

Comment: @userqwert: I can't, but you should be able to as it has only one answer and that answer's score is 0.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same. `Array<T>` and `T[]` are the same type.